# Receiving ORA-01403 when trying to upsert using Oracle MERGE in Perl DBI

Tags: sql, oracle, perl, blob, dbi

I have a Perl script in which I'm trying to use Oracle MERGE statement to upsert data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use DBD::Oracle qw/:ora_types/;
use Data::Dumper;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('db.conn.string', 'user', 'pass', {RaiseError => 1});
$dbh->{LongReadLen} = 16384;

sub main {
        print "started...\n";
        print Dumper { before => select_data() };
        upsert_customer_file_data(112233, 1001, 'sample data here');
        print Dumper { after => select_data() };
        return;
}

sub select_data {
        return $dbh->selectall_arrayref('select * from customer_files');
}

sub upsert_customer_file_data {
        my ($customer_id, $customer_filename_id, $file_data) = @_;
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q/
                MERGE INTO customer_files
                USING DUAL ON ( customer_id = :customer_id AND customer_filename_id = :customer_filename_id )
                WHEN MATCHED THEN
                        UPDATE SET customer_file_data = :file_data,
                                   last_modified_date = SYSDATE
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                        INSERT ( customer_file_id, customer_id, customer_filename_id, customer_file_data, creation_date, last_modified_date )
                        VALUES ( customer_files_seq.nextval, :customer_id, :customer_filename_id, :file_data, SYSDATE, SYSDATE)
        /);
        $sth->bind_param(':customer_id', $customer_id);
        $sth->bind_param(':customer_filename_id', $customer_filename_id);
        $sth->bind_param(':file_data', $file_data, {ora_type => ORA_BLOB});
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->rows();
}

main();
```

When I run the above script I get the following error when it gets to upsert_customer_file_data(112233, 1001, 'sample data here'); :

```
DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-01403: no data found (DBD ERROR: LOB refetch attempted for unsupported statement type (see also ora_auto_lob attribute))
```

When I run this SQL in PLSQL Developer there is no problem, but DBI does not like it and I cannot figure out why.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You most likely have a problem with your variable binding, and the error hints about a LOB, so maybe you need to whittle it down to a simpler query with a blob field, and see if you can get that working.

Comment: It does look like a problem with binding. When I do not specify the ora type, it does work. But it expects hexadecimal string. I'd like this encoding to happen upon binding (or whenever DBD::Oracle does the encoding) so I need to specify ora type.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what the problem was - my `ora_type` is wrong (in binding: `{ora_type => ORA_BLOB}`). I changed it to `SQLT_BIN` and it works perfectly fine. What makes it really confusing is that `{ora_type => ORA_BLOB}` works fine with regular `UPDATE` or `INSERT` but not with `MERGE`

Answer (score 2):

have you tried ora_pers_lob flag ?

```
   my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q/
            MERGE INTO customer_files
            USING DUAL ON ( customer_id = :customer_id AND customer_filename_id =   :customer_filename_id )
            WHEN MATCHED THEN
                    UPDATE SET customer_file_data = :file_data,
                               last_modified_date = SYSDATE
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                    INSERT ( customer_file_id, customer_id, customer_filename_id, customer_file_data, creation_date, last_modified_date )
                    VALUES ( customer_files_seq.nextval, :customer_id, :customer_filename_id, :file_data, SYSDATE, SYSDATE)
    /, ,{ora_pers_lob => 1});
```